# Target brackets AND quotation marks with regex

Tags: regex

I've got a string which looks like this;

```
["Party","Family","Animals"]
```

I want to use a regex expression to target all the quotations marks (") and both brackets ([ and ]).

Later i want to replace them with empty spaces, so i end up like this;

```
Party,Family,Animals
```

All help appreciated!

Comment: Which language are you running?

Comment: Without specifying regex language/tool it is very difficult to get good answers.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm pretty new. I'm running Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
["\]\[]
```

Try this.Replace with `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rA7aS3/10

Answer (score 0):

Java code:

```
String str = "[\"Party\", \"Family\"]";
String regex = "[\"\\[\\]]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
System.out.println(m.replaceAll(""));
```